# An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_362). using MAC on Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, kotlin

I'm trying to build my project and I encounter this error.

## Error

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_362). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
```

I have tried adding this code to my build.gradle Project inside the android block but the error still persist.

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.